# Error de formato de fecha cambio de milenio

Tags: java, date, formato

Al leer la **fecha de nacimiento** del CURP, y al formatearla (`yyyy-MM-dd`), cuando ingreso una CURP con fecha de nacimiento (ejemplo: `XXXX270503XXXXXXXX`) el formateador en vez de poner la fecha como `1927-05-03` la pone como `2027-05-03`, ocasionando que falle.

Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Este es mi código.

```
        String fechaNacimiento = request.getCurp().substring(4, 10);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
        SimpleDateFormat requiredFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date fecha;
        try {
            fecha = dateFormat1.parse(fechaNacimiento);
            fechaNacimiento = requiredFormat1.format(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new Exception("DAFE", e.getMessage(), 500);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Es válida la fecha de nacimiento del CURP qué pruebas? Debe de tener 18 dígitos. Si de la sub cadena de 4 a 2, que representa el año sumándole 1900 es inferior a 1909 súmale otros 100 años.

Comment: Existe información que permita identificar a que siglo corresponde la fecha?

Comment: @Luis te sirvió?

Comment: @Ajeno si muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda

Comment: agrega una de las dos respuestas como la solución a tu problema por favor.

Answer (score 4):

Según la página 
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_%C3%9Anica_de_Registro_de_Poblaci%C3%B3n 
para saber el año 2000 o 1999 se utiliza el dígito 17, si es 0-9 -> 19xx y si es A-Z -> 20xx por lo que sería así:

```
String fechaNacimiento = request.getCurp().substring(4, 10);
if(StringUtils.isNumeric(fechaNacimiento.substring(17,18))){
    fechaNacimiento = "19" + fechaNacimiento;
}else{
    fechaNacimiento = "20" + fechaNacimiento;
}


SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
SimpleDateFormat requiredFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fecha;
try {
    fecha = dateFormat1.parse(fechaNacimiento);
    fechaNacimiento = requiredFormat1.format(fecha);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new Exception("DAFE", e.getMessage(), 500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo en cuenta la información que @Ajeno proporciona respecto al [CURP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_%C3%9Anica_de_Registro_de_Poblaci%C3%B3n) otra manera de resolverlo sería mediante [SimpleDateFormat#set2DigitYearStart(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart%28java.util.Date%29)

`set2DigitYearStart(startDate)` permite **indicar que primeros 2 dígitos se van a tomar en cuenta durante el parseo de una fecha** y si formateamos con el formato abreviado `yy` va a construir la fecha a partir de esos dos primeros dígitos.

El parámetro `startDate` **determina un rango de fechas a considerar**:

> startDate - During parsing, two digit years will be placed in the range startDate to startDate + 100 years.

Es decir, que invocándolo con `1900` tomara el periodo `1900-2000` e invocándolo con `2000` tomará `2000-2100`, en cualquier caso `SimpleDateFormat` va a ubicar la fecha con formato `yy/mm/dd` dentro de ese rango.

**Ejemplos** (seudocodigo):

```
df.set2DigitYearStart(2000)
df.format(88/5/12) -> 2088/5/12

df.set2DigitYearStart(1970)
df.format(70/5/12) -> 2070/5/12

df.set2DigitYearStart(1970)
df.format(90/5/12) -> 1990/5/12
```

*Nótese que en el último caso como el periodo es de 1970 - 2070 y no existe en ese periodo el año 2090 toma 1990*

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/RO1rSb)

**Solución al problema que el OP plantea**:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String fechaNacimiento= "03/05/27";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if(request.getCurp().substring(17,18).matches("[0-9]+")){
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900); // si es un digito corresponde a los 19XX
}else{
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000); // sino, corresponde a 20XX
}
dateFormat.set2DigitYearStart(cal.getTime()); // a partir de este punto dateFormat conoceque dos primeros digitos tomar al parsear
cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(fechaNacimiento));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

**¿Que sucede si no indicamos explicitamente el siglo?** En la documentación de [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) se menciona:

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
>   For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat
>   instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be
>   interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be
>   interpreted as May 4, 1964.

Es decir, `SimpleDateFormat` va a tomar en cuenta el período `(fecha creación - 80 años)` a `(fecha creación + 20 años)` y dependiendo de en que siglo caiga la fecha a parsear determinará que primeros dos dígitos utilizar.